# why set overall code coverage will be atleast 75%

Tags: code-coverage

Overall code coverage set from salesforce is 75% we can cover upto 100% but why they set for 75% only not set 100%.

Comment: Because 100% is not realistic for a lot of orgs. In a lot of code you have to trick it during tests to cover lines thus you not even testin real scenarios. The focus should be on functional testing anyway not a %

Comment: Diminishing returns bro... you are welcome to shoot for 100%

Comment: We aim for 90%. Only good argument I’ve heard for 100% overall is that it guarantees that there are no 0% (completely untested) classes hiding. But high coverage does not directly equate to well tested.